# converge of a symbolic infinite series

Tags: python, sum, sympy

I would like to symbolically determine the convergence value of an infinite series. Using Mathematica and the Sum command, I obtained a result (I don’t know if correct) and I tried to reproduce it with Python but it cannot elaborate it.

My code is:

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.abc import k, x, d,f
from sympy import Sum, oo

result = sym.Sum(x**(2*(k-1))*sym.exp(sym.I*(2*k-1)*d), (k, 1, oo)).doit()
```

Is there something wrong with it?
Is there a more effective way to perform this operation?

Thank you

Comment: It seems that the algorithm in sympy does not yet handle this case:  https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21557

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to calculate this in the way that you tried although perhaps it isn't implemented yet in sympy. The sum is a geometric series so we can calculate it somewhat manually:

```
In [82]: s = Sum(x**(2*(k-1))*sym.exp(I*(2*k-1)*d), (k, 1, oo))

In [83]: s
Out[83]: 
  ∞                          
 ___                         
 ╲                           
  ╲    2⋅k - 2  ⅈ⋅d⋅(2⋅k - 1)
  ╱   x       ⋅ℯ             
 ╱                           
 ‾‾‾                         
k = 1                        

In [84]: s2 = factor_terms(powsimp(factor_terms(s.rewrite(exp).expand()), deep=True))

In [85]: s2
Out[85]: 
        ∞                      
       ___                     
       ╲                       
 -ⅈ⋅d   ╲    2⋅k⋅(ⅈ⋅d + log(x))
ℯ    ⋅  ╱   ℯ                  
       ╱                       
       ‾‾‾                     
      k = 1                    
───────────────────────────────
                2              
               x               

In [86]: Sum(x**k, (k, 1, oo)).doit().subs(x, exp(2*(I*d + log(x)))) * exp(-I*d) / x**2
Out[86]: 
⎛⎧     2  2⋅ⅈ⋅d                   ⎞      
⎜⎪    x ⋅ℯ                │ 2│    ⎟      
⎜⎪ ───────────────    for │x │ < 1⎟      
⎜⎪    2  2⋅ⅈ⋅d                    ⎟      
⎜⎪ - x ⋅ℯ      + 1                ⎟      
⎜⎪                                ⎟      
⎜⎪  ∞                             ⎟      
⎜⎪ ____                           ⎟  -ⅈ⋅d
⎜⎨ ╲                              ⎟⋅ℯ    
⎜⎪  ╲                             ⎟      
⎜⎪   ╲             k              ⎟      
⎜⎪   ╱  ⎛ 2  2⋅ⅈ⋅d⎞    otherwise  ⎟      
⎜⎪  ╱   ⎝x ⋅ℯ     ⎠               ⎟      
⎜⎪ ╱                              ⎟      
⎜⎪ ‾‾‾‾                           ⎟      
⎜⎪k = 1                           ⎟      
⎝⎩                                ⎠      
─────────────────────────────────────────
                     2                   
                    x
```

You can test the result numerically if you substitute particular values for `x` and `d`:

```
In [95]: s3 = Sum(x**k, (k, 1, oo)).doit().subs(x, exp(2*(I*d + log(x)))) * exp(-I*d) / x**2

In [96]: s.subs(x, S.Half).subs(d, 1).n()
Out[96]: 0.318932163677498 + 0.827845692253729⋅ⅈ

In [97]: s3.subs(x, S.Half).subs(d, 1).n()
Out[97]: 0.318932163677498 + 0.827845692253729⋅ⅈ
```